# Shift + Enter » Multiple Line

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, shift, enter

firstly English isn't my native language, sorry if I have any mistakes.

There is message sending problem in the function, I've played with Jquery codes but I couldn't fix it.

When I press the Enter, message reach to receiver, that's good.
But when I press the Shift with Enter, message reach to receiver again,
I want to create new line when press the both keys.

Jquery codes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('input#chat').bind('keydown', function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode==13) {
   // Store the message into var
   var message = $('input#chat').val();
   var id = $('#chat').attr('class');
   if(message) {
    // Remove chat errors if any
    $('.chat-error').remove();
    
    // Show the progress animation
    $('.message-loader').show();
    
    // Reset the chat input area   
    document.getElementById("chat").style.height = "25px";
    $('input#chat').val('');
```

Comment: I've not done much keyboard handling in Javascript, but I'm betting that if you have Enter pressed no matter what else is there, `e.keyCode === 13` will be true and thus effectively be the same as pressing enter. An idea is to handle modifiers before this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it ?

```
 if(e.shiftKey && e.keyCode==13){
     // Don't fill
 } else if(e.keyCode==13){
     e.preventDefault();
     // Store the message into var
        var message = $('input#chat').val();
        var id = $('#chat').attr('class');
        if(message) {
        ........................
 }
```

Comment: I tried but I should  add jquery multiple line code at "// your code here"
but I couldn't find that code..

Comment: i have updated my answers. I added e.preventDefault();  ... it will excepting SHIFT + ENTER to add new line. and another combination or just enter will do sending your message

Comment: I tried, but this time enter is doesn't work / enter+shift too.

Comment: what version of jQuery you used ?

Comment: I don't know, I am not good at jQuery, how can I learn version?

Comment: mmm, try to change .bind() with .live() and .on()

Comment: I did, it doesn't work.. I trying this on localhost, can you help me with connect to my pc?

Answer (score 0):

In this, while the shift key is pressed a boolean prevents the code from being run.

```js
var ShiftDown = false; //Is false when not being pressed, true when being pressed
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('input#chat').keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.which === 16) {
            //Shift key is pressed
            ShiftDown = true;
        }else if(e.which === 13){
            //Code will only run if Shift key is not pressed
            if(ShiftDown === false){
       // Store the message into var
       var message = $('input#chat').val();
       var id = $('#chat').attr('class');
       if(message) {
        // Remove chat errors if any
        $('.chat-error').remove();
    
        // Show the progress animation
        $('.message-loader').show();
    
        // Reset the chat input area   
        document.getElementById("chat").style.height = "25px";
                    $('input#chat').val('');
                }
            }
        }
    })
    $('input#chat').keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.which === 16){
            //Shift key is no longer pressed
            ShiftDown = false;
        }
    });
}
```

I've just changed

```
$('input#chat').bind('keydown',function(e){})
```

to

```
$('input#chat').keydown(function(e){})
```

Comment: I did this, but now key functions are completely deactived and the time format is "2015-03-05T11:23:26+01:00" :/

Comment: I don't know what caused that. How odd.

Comment: Just changed the key function method